# How does random graph generator work in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I used the [source code of Networkx](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Python/Network/NetworkX/networkx-1.1/networkx/generators/random_graphs.py.htm) to generate a random graph with Poisson degree distribution.

I change some parts of codes that I need as follows:

```
import random
import networkx
import math
from networkx.generators.classic import empty_graph

def gnp_random_graph(n, p, seed=None):
    """Return a random graph G_{n,p}.

    Parameters
    ----------
    n : int
        The number of nodes.
    p : float
        Probability for edge creation.
        possible edges: n[n-1]/2
    seed : int, optional
        Seed for random number generator (default=None). 

    """
    #My sample  
    z = 4 #mean degree
    n = 10 #Number of nodes
    p = math.exp**(-z)*z**(k)/(math.factorial(k)) ##I add this myself #k is missing   

    #This part is from the source 
    G=empty_graph(n)

    if not seed is None:
        random.seed(seed)

    for u in xrange(n):
        for v in xrange(u+1,n):
            if random.random() < p:
                G.add_edge(u,v)
return G
```

In the last part for generating edges, I don't understand how it count degree and compare with p(Probability distribution of degree(k))? For me it looks like it generate a random number btw (0,1). But how one should use domain for p and compare the random number with p(k)?

Answer (score 3):

Unless the number of nodes/edges are large, this gives a bernoulli distribution. You can get networkx to give you a poisson degree distribution easily.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import poisson

def poissongraph(n,mu):
    z= np.zeros(n) #n is number of nodes
    for i in range(n):
        z[i]=poisson.rvs(mu) #mu is the expected value
    G=expected_degree_graph(z)
    return G
```

Comment: This won't do what you're claiming.  The expected degree graph is a graph whose nodes are assigned an expected degree and then edges are placed randomly in such a way that the assigned value is the expected degree.  To see this, set all nodes to have the same expected degree, and you'll get an Erdos-Renyi graph (with an almost Poisson degree distribution).

Comment: What you should use instead is `nx.configuration_model(z)`, which may refuse to run if the degrees don't sum to an even value, and may create self-loops and repeated edges.

Answer (score 1):

This works, because generating a graph this way (using Brenoulli-sampling), will result in a graph with a Poisson degree-distribution (explained in detail [here (pdf)](http://www.facweb.iitkgp.ernet.in/~niloy/COURSE/Spring2006/CNT/notes/scribe_05CS6005_1.pdf)).

Comment: I didn't explain good. The p(poisson distribution), I add it by hand, in the original code p(k) and k are not mentioned and it made me confused :(